# r - How to determine the correlation between unordered categorical variables and individuals?

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

I have a matrix with several unordered categorical variables. Each row represents a type of individual. Each column represents the number of times each type of individual was found to be in that particular condition.

```
Type    coal    cobalt  concrete    copper  gold
A       12      0       0           19      5
B       5       0       0           11      0
C       4       2       0           14      1
D       1       3       15          0       1
E       0       20      2           1       9
```

My question is very simple: I want to know if there is a correlation between the type of the individual (A, B or C) with a particular condition (copper, gold, etc).

Which test should I use? If possible, I would like to get the answer by using R.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have data sets $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ and $Y_1,\cdots,Y_n$, then you can compute their correlation with the following formula:

$$Cor(X,Y) = \frac{\sum (X_i-\bar{X})(Y_i-\bar{Y})}{\sqrt{\sum (X_i-\bar{X})^2\sum(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2}}$$

(where $\bar{X}$ denotes the average value of the $X_i$'s).  This is accomplished in $R$ with the following command:

```
cor(x,y)
```

That being said, it is unclear what two data sets you are trying to find the correlation for.  Finding the correlation between a type (A,B,C) and a condition (copper, gold, etc.) would not make any sense.  You could, however, find the correlation between two different types (A and B, for example), or between conditions (copper and gold).

**Edit**: I think you might want to do a test for independence between categorical variables...if this is the case then [this](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/goodness-fit/chi-squared-test-independence) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think it does not make much sense to look for a correlation here.

Wild guess: 
This looks like the result of a cluster analysis to me.

Read these `=>` as 'corresponds best with'

Cluster...

```
E => cobalt or gold
D => concrete
C => copper
B => copper
A => copper or coal
```

Difficult to tell without domain knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not sure what you would like to compute - your exemplary data only has one observation for each type, which makes the computation of a co-variation aka correlation impossible.

If you‘re interested in prediction, for example the probability that a new observation with values for coal, cobalt, concrete, copper and gold will be of a certain type, linear discriminant analysis (LDA) might be what you're looking for. LDA is implemented in the [MASS package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MASS/index.html) and nicely explained on r-bloggers: http://www.r-bloggers.com/computing-and-visualizing-lda-in-r/

Still, you'll need more observations per Type to use LDA.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to calculate is called mutual information. "It measures the average reduction in uncertainty about x that results from learning the value of y; or vice versa, the average amount of information that x conveys about y", y is the person type and x is the vector of condition counts.

http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/itila/book.html chapter 8.1

And this is the R package description  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/entropy/entropy.pdf